# how to find unknown string from a known pattern ? python re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I have an html text with strings such as
sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2

I want to extract all the strings that appear after "sentence-transformers/".

I tried `models = re.findall("sentence-transformers/"+"(\w+)", text)` but it only output the first word (paraphrase) while I want the full "paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2 "

Also I don't know the len(paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2 ) a priori.

How can I extract the full string?

Many thanks,
Ele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that `-` is not considered a word character, and you are only searching for word characters. The following regex works on your example:

```py
text = 'sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2'
models = re.findall(r'sentence-transformers/([\w-]+)', text)

assert models[0] == 'paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2'
```